# How to send nested tuple with Python Requests?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm a PHP-Developer and trying to create a Python-Script to talk to my application. Here is the code. Where is my mistake?

**# Python-Code on Client**

```
import json
import requests

POST_URL = 'https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello'

payload_map    = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
payload_tuples = [
    ('key1', 'value1'),
    ('key2', 'value2')
]

payload_mixed  = {
    'name': 'John',
    'surname': 'Doe',
    'Age': 30,
    'log': payload_tuples
}

print(json.dumps(payload_mixed))    # renders {"Age": 30, "surname": "Doe", "name": "John", "log": [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]}

r = requests.post(POST_URL, data=payload_mixed)

print(r.url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

**PHP-Code on Server**

```
$response = (isset($_POST['log']) ? $_POST['log'] : $_POST);
echo json_encode($response, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
exit;
```

**OUTPUT in Python-Console on Client**

```
# with object payload_map as object 'log' in object payload_mixed
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
key1

# with object payload_tuples as object 'log' in object payload_mixed
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
value2
```

Why is it that the "log"-Object is never properly rendered, but only a fragment of it?

If I execute this command

```
r = requests.post(POST_URL, data=payload_map)
```

then the output is

```
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
{u'key2': u'value2', u'key1': u'value1'}
```

If I execute this command

```
r = requests.post(POST_URL, data=payload_tuples)
```

then the output is

```
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
{u'key2': u'value2', u'key1': u'value1'}
```

Why does my nested object not render like this? I require it to render like so:

```
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
{u'Age': u'30', u'surname': u'Doe', u'name': u'John', u'log': {u'key2': u'value2', u'key1': u'value1'}}
```

**EDIT :**
It was suggested to wrap the payload object with `json.dumps()`. I changed and see the following output:

```
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
[]
```

Changing my PHP-Script to debug `$_REQUEST` rathern than `$_POST` reveals that no POST data is received:

```
$response = $_REQUEST;
echo json_encode($response, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
exit;
```

Output:

```
https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello
200
{u'task': u'sayhello', u'service': u'api', u'format': u'json'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import json
import requests

POST_URL = 'https://corporate-url.com/index.php?service=api&format=json&task=sayhello'

payload_map    = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
payload_tuples = [
    ('key1', 'value1'),
    ('key2', 'value2')
]

payload_mixed  = {
    'name': 'John',
    'surname': 'Doe',
    'Age': 30,
    'log': payload_tuples
}

r = requests.post(POST_URL, data=json.dumps(payload_mixed)) #add json.dumps()

print(r.url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Wrapping the `payload_mixed`object with `json.dumps()` causes that `$_POST` on the server is completely empty - output: `[]`. If I change the server script to debug `$_REQUEST` it debugs only the URL query parameters. I updated my initial post and added a new `print()` command right below `payload_mixed` with a hint how `payload_mixed` lookes like when it is passed to `requests.post()`. Can you explain why this doesn't work as intended? Did I miss something?